# Is there any way to increase brightness of light with mirrors/other easy to find objects?

Tags: optics

Increase the brightness of a laser with things that are easy to find. How can this be done with household items or without?

Comment: You probably need to explain what you mean by brightness. Power? Power per area, power per solid angle, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can't be done. You can *focus* a laser to some (often quite small) degree with lenses, which makes part of the beam more intense at some specific distance, but you can't make it any brighter. Indeed, using real lenses, you expect to lose some of the light to attenuation, so overall you're making it less bright.

A $10~\rm mW$ laser is a $10~\rm mW$ laser- it has a fixed amount of power. All mirrors, lenses, and such can do is shift around where that power eventually hits.